# Wrong video card driver loaded by the system fater updates. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers

After installing updates in Ubuntu 12.04, system does not recognize my video driver (ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series) .  The system settings show VESA: CYPRESS driver. My xorg.conf was cleared.

I have reinstalled AMD Catalyst Driver; the xorg.conf was populated with some data but unfortunately, it did not help.
Is it possible to have a fix for it?
If not, how can I load the kernel that I had prior to updates.

I attempted to move to the default video driver while troubleshooting, but my PC fans started spinning out of control.
This malfunction causes lots of visual noise (such as salt & pepper) on my display.

My PC Processor: Intel® Core™ i7 CPU 930 @ 2.80GHz × 8

OS Type: 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

check with lsmod command, find what video card is loaded.